# Can't get access to the clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have input search and table, that generates automatically if I change input.

```
<div class="search">
  <form action="" method="post" class="searchform" >
    <input type="search" name="" placeholder="Search" class="inputsearchform" ng-model="search"/>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="" class="submitsearchform" />
  </form>
</div>
<div class="songlist">
  <table id="songlistTableR" ng-app='test_table' ng-controller='main_control'>   
   <tr><th>Name</th><th>Link</th></tr>    
   <tr ng-repeat="data in loaded | filter:search">
     <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>{{data.song_name}}</td>
     <td><a href="{{data.link}}" target='_blank'>Youtube</a></td>     
   </tr>
 </table>      
</div>
```

JS script for generating data in table is:

```
var app = angular.module('test_table', []);
var n = [];
app.controller('main_control',function($scope,$http, $rootScope){
    load();
    function load(){
        $http.get("http://localhost:7001/load").success(function(data){
            $rootScope.loaded=data; 
            n = data;
        });
    }       
});
```

I also have code, that shows table when input.value != 0

```
$('.inputsearchform').bind('input', function() {
    if($(this).val() == 0){
        songlistTableR.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    else{
        songlistTableR.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }   
});
```

Everything works good, but I can't get access to element `.fa.fa-plus` when it's clicked. The only two ways, that work are putting `$(".fa.fa-plus").click(function(){});` in `bind` event or creating function outside `window.onload` that will work if I put in HTML file onclick for `.fa.fa-plus` element.

First method is bad, because if I change input more than one time, click function will work every time, even if I didn't click on this element.

Second method also isn't appropriate because I need to know `index` of clicked element.

Can anybody advise me a solution?

**UPD** Sorry for interruption, I solved this problem. I changed the version of `Jquery` to 2.2.2 and now it's working. Thanks for helping!

Comment: You really should be handling click events with angular if you are using angular. In many cases, using jQuery to handle events that angular also handles causes issues. Yes, there are exceptions, and it definitely can be done, but in this case, you definitely should use @Vanojx1's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try to attach the event handler to the `document` but filtering on your selector. In this way even if the inner DOM changes, your handler will always intercept the event triggered by elements having the class `fa fa-plus`

```
$(document).on("click",".fa.fa-plus", function(){});
```

As @mhodges pointed out, this is a [delegated event](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Comment: This is called event delegation, just FYI. Docs here: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it doesn't work. I tried to put it inside `window.onload` and outside, but I have an error: `$(...).on is not a function`, even I included jquery (order: jquery > angular > main script)

Comment: Make sure jquery is included *before* this line

Answer (score 3):

try to change this:

```
<td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>{{data.song_name}}</td>
```

with:

```
<td><a ng-click="doSomething($event)" ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>{{data.song_name}}</a></td>
```

then in the controller:

```
$scoope.doSomething() = function(event){
     do what you need 
}
```

just handle events in the angular way